# Black lines when adding custom control to a panel with Control's DockStyle set to Top

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, user-controls

I am trying to add a custom user control using following code:

```
void addComment(string comment)
{
     commentContainer.Controls.Add(new Comment(comment) { Dock = DockStyle.Top});
}
```

But this is giving me following result:
[image]
But when I tried to do this

```
void addComment(string comment)
{
     commentContainer.Controls.Add(new Comment(comment) { Dock = DockStyle.None});
}
```

The result was the following screenshot:
[image]

And now its showing the user control but all overlapped on each other. I want to show all of them stacked from top to bottom. But when I set the `DockStyle` to Top to achieve this, the first screen shot comes up. Please tell me why its happening?

**UPDATE**

`Comment` is the user control that I want to add. I don't know what these black lines are but I think these are shrunken `Comment` user controls that are so shrunken that looking like a thin line.

Comment: Need more information about what you are trying to achieve, what Comment is, and what this black line is? (looks like a black square on second image)

Comment: see my update on question

Comment: I understand that comment is a user control but as far as I can see it could just be a blank control... are you after anchor instead of dock?

Comment: You mean form auto rezize?

Comment: [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) (Top in particular)

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you are talking about the auto resize. Well I found the solution to this problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my problem. I was setting the `Comment` control's `AutoSize` property to `true`. When I set it `false`, it worked. Thanks @Sayse, your comment gave me hint about it.